# Pasar diferentes DataTable a una misma funcion en VB

Tags: vb.net, datatable

Buenos días, necesito saber si puedo hacer lo siguiente o como hacerlo, actualmente yo envió en una función un `DataTable` para completar o hacer una cantidad de cálculos pendientes, pero ahora necesito pasar las cinco u ocho tablas y no quiero hacer una función por cada una de ellas, actualmente hago esto:

```
Public Function mpxporcentaje(ByVal poRow as dsprocesos.tblprocesoRow) as integer

for each tblrow as dsprocesos.tblprocesoRow In dsprocesos.tblproceso
  cuenta = cuenta + 1
next
```

Me funciona pero ahora necesito pasar las cinco o las n tablas que tengo, como puedo hacer para pasar las diferentes tablas como parámetro y no especificar una, todas tienen el mismo campo que necesito.

Saludos

Comment: esto es un poquito mas complicado de lo que parece, pero se puede hacer, solo que cuando pases una vas a tener que saber cual pasaste.. o tener una clase base y que todo el resto herede de esas.. que es dsprocesos.tblprocesoRow?

Comment: Que tal @alfredo.avmb por qué no utilizas un DataSet,? así puedes tener n tablas en una colección de datos.

Comment: Buenos dias, estimado Julio, estoy utilizando dataset, me podrias explicar o documentar como realizar lo que estoy tratando de hacer.